# Chrome on windows adding extra divs and elements to my HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome

While my code is as simple as this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello, World!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open it in the dev tools, I am seeing this:

```
    <html>
<head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css"></style>
</head>
        <body>
            <p>Hello, World!</p>


    <div class="drop-hint" id="drop-to-share-hint" style="display: none; background-image: url(chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/dropToShareHint.png); background-size: 67px 327px;"><a class="share-btn-close"></a><a class="btn-options"></a><div class="drop-hint-bubble" id="drop-hint-bubble-share" style="display: none; background-image: url(chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/dropToShareHintBubble.png); background-size: 253px 79px;"></div></div><div class="drop-hint" id="drop-to-search-hint" style="display: none; background-image: url(chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/dropToSearchHint.png); background-size: 67px 327px;"><a class="search-btn-close"></a><a class="btn-options"></a><div class="drop-hint-bubble" id="drop-hint-bubble-search" style="display: none; background-image: url(chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/dropToSearchHintBubble.png); background-size: 215px 79px;"></div></div><div class="dropAreaContainer" style="display: none; right: 0px;"><div class="searchDropArea" style="width: 142px; height: 16.6667%; background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.901961);"><span class="disable-manipulations"></span><img src="chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/web-search-content.png" style="max-height: 81px; height: 90%; background-color: transparent;" class="disable-manipulations"></div><div class="searchDropArea" style="width: 142px; height: 16.6667%; background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.901961);"><span class="disable-manipulations"></span><img src="chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/video-search-content.png" style="max-height: 40px; height: 90%; background-color: transparent;" class="disable-manipulations"></div><div class="searchDropArea" style="width: 142px; height: 16.6667%; background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.901961);"><span class="disable-manipulations"></span><img src="chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/google-images-content.png" style="max-height: 88px; height: 90%; background-color: transparent;" class="disable-manipulations"></div><div class="searchDropArea" style="width: 142px; height: 16.6667%; background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.901961);"><span class="disable-manipulations"></span><img src="chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/google-translate-content.png" style="max-height: 82px; height: 90%; background-color: transparent;" class="disable-manipulations"></div><div class="searchDropArea" style="width: 142px; height: 16.6667%; background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.901961);"><span class="disable-manipulations"></span><img src="chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/wikipedia-content.png" style="max-height: 86px; height: 90%; background-color: transparent;" class="disable-manipulations"></div><div class="dropAreaSettings" style="width: 142px; height: 16.6667%; background-color: rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.901961);"><span class="disable-manipulations"></span><img src="chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/btn_settings.png" style="max-height: 25px; height: 90%; background-color: transparent;" class="disable-manipulations">
</div>
</div>
<div class="dropAreaContainer" style="display: none; left: 0px;">
<div class="shareDropArea" style="width: 142px; height: 16.6667%; background-color: rgba(60, 90, 152, 0.901961);"><span class="disable-manipulations"></span><img src="chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/facebook-share-content.png" style="max-height: 25px; height: 90%; background-color: transparent;" class="disable-manipulations"></div><div class="shareDropArea" style="width: 142px; height: 16.6667%; background-color: rgba(233, 246, 255, 0.901961);"><span class="disable-manipulations"></span><img src="chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/twitter-content.png" style="max-height: 23px; height: 90%; background-color: transparent;" class="disable-manipulations"></div><div class="shareDropArea" style="width: 142px; height: 16.6667%; background-color: rgba(235, 235, 235, 0.901961);"><span class="disable-manipulations"></span><img src="chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/pinterest-content.png" style="max-height: 28px; height: 90%; background-color: transparent;" class="disable-manipulations"></div><div class="shareDropArea" style="width: 142px; height: 16.6667%; background-color: rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.901961);"><span class="disable-manipulations"></span><img src="chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/google-plus-center-content.png" style="max-height: 56px; height: 90%; background-color: transparent;" class="disable-manipulations"></div><div class="shareDropArea" style="width: 142px; height: 16.6667%; background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.901961);"><span class="disable-manipulations"></span><img src="chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/providers/linkedin-content.png" style="max-height: 31px; height: 90%; background-color: transparent;" class="disable-manipulations"></div><div class="dropAreaSettings" style="width: 142px; height: 16.6667%; background-color: rgba(58, 58, 58, 0.901961);"><span class="disable-manipulations"></span><img src="chrome-extension://cipmepknanmbbaneimacddfemfbfgpgo/images/content/btn_settings.png" style="max-height: 25px; height: 90%; background-color: transparent;" class="disable-manipulations"></div></div></body></html>
```

Also when my console logs this for no reason:

```
DragAndDropController.js:89 extension connect
DragAndDropController.js:185 onExtensionMsgReceived:ddBgIsReady
DragAndDropController.js:185 onExtensionMsgReceived:getSettings
DragAndDropController.js:185 onExtensionMsgReceived:windowIsActivated
DragAndDropController.js:185 onExtensionMsgReceived:getSearchSources
DragAndDropController.js:185 onExtensionMsgReceived:getShareSources
DragAndDropController.js:185 onExtensionMsgReceived:windowIsActivated
DragAndDropController.js:185 onExtensionMsgReceived:ddBgIsReady
DragAndDropController.js:185 onExtensionMsgReceived:getSettings
DragAndDropController.js:185 onExtensionMsgReceived:getSearchSources
DragAndDropController.js:185 onExtensionMsgReceived:getShareSources
DragAndDropController.js:185 onExtensionMsgReceived:ddBgIsReady
DragAndDropController.js:185 onExtensionMsgReceived:getSettings
DragAndDropController.js:185 onExtensionMsgReceived:getSearchSources
DragAndDropController.js:185 onExtensionMsgReceived:getShareSources
```

Please suggest some way to get rid of all the extra black magic that chrome is doing to my code.

Comment: Are you facing this issue in Chrome or Torch browser?

Answer (score 3):

Please check what extensions you have installed on chrom sometimes these things can be added from them for example add blocker adds it to the bottom to it can be run if need be.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a Handy extension by which you can easily enable/disable all other extension in Handy way.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-manager-aka-sw/lpleipinonnoibneeejgjnoeekmbopbc?hl=en